# how to align footer text on the left and on the right same as like google

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at the [www.google.com](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=BsTkV9wuivLwB6bQtuAE).
There, I have footer with *Advertising*, *Bussiness* and *About* on the left and *Privacy*, *Settings*, *Terms*..etc on the right at the bottom of the page .

I am new too  developer i am trying to develop same as google page just with html and css, without any functions.

Here is my Html page code

```css
selector {
  property: value;
}
h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 180px;
  border: 0;
}
h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 120px;
  border: 0;
}
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  top: -160px;
  right: -560px;
  width: 25px;
}
img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  top: 40%;
  bottom: 60%;
  left: 40%;
  margin: auto;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 400px;
  background: no-repeat left;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 500px;
}
.venu {
  width: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: 2.png;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 45%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55%;
  bottom: 60%;
  left: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}
p {
  position: fixed;
  top: 75%;
  bottom: 60%;
  left: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  left: -800px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="2.css" />
  <title>Google</title>
  <style>
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      background-color: #e0e0e0;
      color: #696969;
      padding: 14px 25px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    a:hover,
    a:active {
      background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <img src="22.png" class="ribbon" />
  </div>
  <button class="button">Sign in</button>
  <h3>Gmail</h3>
  <h4>Images</h4>
  <img src="download.png" />
  <input type="text" class="venu">
  <p>Google.co.in offered in: English Hindi Tamil Telugu Kanada Malayalam</p>
  <div id="footer">
    <h4 class="left">Advertising Business About</h4>
    <h4 class="right">Privacy Terms  Settings  Use Google.com</h4>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="" target="www.Google.com">Google Search</a>
  <a href="" target="www.Google.com">I'm Feeling Lucky</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Please let me know if there is anything I am missing to get the footer.

Comment: whats the issue your facing?

Answer (score 1):

Make two divs such as leftDiv  and rightDiv.
In left Div, enter the list of elements required.
Do the same for right div.

```
.leftDiv{
    float:left;
}
.rightDiv{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<footer>` for setting footer

Here in your, code replace `<h4>` tags inside the `<div id="footer"></div>` with the `<footer>` tag. Just like this:
`<div id="footer">
    <footer>Advertising Business About</footer>
 </div>`

and you can also align your footer content by adding `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Look at their code, I have made a snippet similar to theirs. Put `float: right` to the element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content.left {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.content.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <span class="content left">Some contents here</span>
  <span class="content right">Some contents here</span>
</footer>
```